# Passing template type parameter as a type of template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

Just curious: with C++17 and later we can use an `auto` placeholder for non-type template parameters:

```
template<typename A, auto B>
class C {
public:
    A foo() { return B; }
};
```

But can we pass instead of `auto` the template type parameter `A`?

**example.cpp**

```
template<typename A, A B>
class C {
public:
    A foo() { return B; }
};

int main()
{
    C<int, 5> c;
    std::cout << c.foo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Well in practice we can, and clang with -std=c++11 allows to do that.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp
$ ./a.out
5
```

But what about the Standard? I didn't find any explicit rule for this.
Thanks!

Comment: I think its possible, except for the string literals. [See this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg#nontype-4.example-1)

Comment: I've edited to your question to include the language-lawyer tag. That ought to draw the crowd you're looking for (i.e. references to the Standard).

Answer (score 2):

> But can we pass instead of "auto" template type parameter defined at left?

Sure. It's the old way.

But the `auto` way permit to avoid to pass the type `A`.

In C++17 you can write

```
template <auto B>
class C {
public:
    auto foo() { return B; }
};
```

so there is no needs to pass the type `A`.

I don't know a way to do the same in C++11/C++14.

I mean: if you want, in C++11/C++14 pass a value to a template... if the type is fixed, there is no problem

```
template <int I>
```

but the type itself can be different, in C++11/C++14 you have to pass first the type, then the value as in your example.cpp

```
template <typename T, T A>
```

The problem, in the old way, is that if you want to call that type of template, you have to be redundant and write something as

```
C<decltype(x), x>  some_C_variable;
```

and the only ways I know to avoid this redundancies is pass through a make function (something as `make_tuple()`)  or a C-style macro.

In C++17 you can simply write

```
C<x>   some_C_variable
```

and, inside the C template class/struct, the type of `x` can be obtained from `decltype(B)`.

For C++17 standard references...

First of all, the `auto` is defined a "placeolder"

From 10.1.7.4 (The `auto` specifier), point 1

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifier*s are used to designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an initializer.

This was true also in C++11/C++14

But C++17 standard add, for "Template parameters" (17.1), in point 4 enumeration, the new point 4.6

> 4. A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> [...]
>
> (4.6) a type that contains a placeholder type (10.1.7.4)

Comment: Thanks! May be you know any standard reference, or just link to cppreference where this possibility is described?

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy - I'm not a language lawyer so I've difficult to find the exact reference; for cppreference you can see the [auto page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (see point 8)

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy - added a couple of C++17 standard references; hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters can be divided in:

```
1. Type parameters
2. Non type parameters
3. Template template parameters
```

In your case, the statement `A B` is a non type template parameter whose type is the template type parameter `A`.

Keep in mind, in your example you do:

```
return B;
```

the above statement would fail on types `A` that are not `copy constructible` (This is easily expressed by a concept).

Keep in mind(and as was pointed in the comments), C++17 mandates copy elision.

Comment: "In your case, the statement A B is a non type template parameter whose type is the template type parameter A."

I know that.
The whole question is it allowed by standard or not.

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy since it names a feature, i.e. a non template parameter why wouldn't ? I can take a look at the standard later but I would be surprised if that wasn't the case.

Comment: In C++17 `return B` does not require that `A` be copy or move constructible, due to [mandatory copy/move elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) of prvalues.

Comment: @Oktalist I had that written(if you see the history of edits) but I removed it to narrow it down. Sine you mentioned it should be back up there to avoid confusion. Thanks for pointing out. (even if pre C++17 were copy elision was not guaranteed, most compilers I know would elide the copy)

Comment: Pre C++17, a move or copy constructor was still required, even if it's elided.

Comment: @Oktalist pre C++17 Isn't the case that the compiler would generate the copy and move constructor for the class (ofc if it's not deleted etc)? Then the copy would be elided(most likely) even if it isn't enforced by the standard ?

Comment: Of course, an implicit copy/move constructor would be sufficient.